# How to determine which Interface belongs to each Network Destination - Java?

Tags: java, networking, interface, routes

If my host is connected to several subnets (through different routes), how can I find the corresponding Interface for a given ip?

In other words, when trying to access another host (or Network Destination if you use route print in Windows, cmd), how can I read the actual Interface for that Network Destination?

Right now I am considering opening a cmd window, using route print, then parsing the output and writing my own method to determine if ip address xxx.xx.xx.xxx belongs to Network Destination xxx.xx.0.0, mask [...] and then reading the corresponding Interface value, but surely there has to  be an easier way.

Comment: You mean you want to get IP address and subnet mask for all interfaces? Or get network interface by IP address?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Let me rephrase so I'm sure I'm getting this right. I want to know for a given IP in my network WHICH interface from my PC communicates with it. E.G. if I have 2 interfaces 11.135.20.30 that is in one subnet and 11.135.20.35 that is in another subnet, how can I know from the IP with which I'm communicating which interface is in use.

Comment: That depends on routing set in OS. But if you want to guess from destination IP address, then you should know IP of each interface and subnet mask. And you can retrieve IP of each interface and subnet mask with Java. You can't know routing set with direct help from Java, for that the method you are using (with CMD command and parsing it) is fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's what I also found out so far but was hoping for a more platform-independent solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is there was no real short answer to this one.

I wanted to see which of my interfaces communicated with device 11.135.20.30 (for example).

What I did was ping the device I wanted to reach and then strip and read the response packages. There I found the destination IP and therefore the interface address I was looking for.